# How to use Ant Design Upload component with firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ant-design-pro

I am working on a React project with firebase and ant design. I can't upload file to firebase from ant design upload component. Can you give me with a little example

what is the meaning of this : action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76'. I want to upload to firebase storage from ant design component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.